# How could I untar many tar files seperately with one command?

Tags: shell, tar, xargs

I have many tar files like this: aa.tar, bb.tar, cc.tar, ....

I would like to untar them to their own directories such as aa/, bb/, cc/ ...

I tried this:

```
ls | xargs -n1 -I {} tar -xvf {} -C `basename {} .tar`
```

which does not work. It seems that the {} cannot be used as both whole tar file name and its file name without `.tar`.

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `{}` in the command substitution (calling `basename`) as that is executed *before* even `xargs` is called. This means `tar` would try to change directory to a directory called `{}` (literally) for each archive.

Use a `for` loop, there's no need for `xargs`.  e.g.

```
for t in *.tar ; do
  bn="$(basename "$t" .tar)"
  mkdir -p "$bn"
  tar -xvf "$t" -C "$bn"
done
```

See also: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your command does not work is that the command substitution (the bit you wrote with backticks) would be executed once, before `xargs` is even started.

Since you tagged this with `xargs`, I thought I'd give an `xargs`-based solution.

First, to unpack a single one of your `tar` archives, you could use

```
dir=${archive%.tar}
mkdir -- "$dir" && tar -x -f "$archive" -C "$dir"
```

... assuming that `$archive` contains the filename of the `tar` archive and that the archive is plain (not compressed).

You could obviously loop this with

```
for archive in *.tar; do
    dir=${archive%.tar}
    mkdir -- "$dir" && tar -x -f "$archive" -C "$dir"
done
```

but that would not let us use some of the commonly (albeit non-standard) features of `xargs`, such as running multiple commands in parallel.

To run our initial commands, four at a time, the names of the `tar` archives has to be fed into `xargs` on its standard input.

We can do that with

```
printf '%s\n' *.tar | xargs ...
```

This obviously assumes that no archive has a name that contains embedded newlines, but you could work around that by using

```
printf '%s\0' *.tar | xargs -0 ...
```

if your implementation of `xargs` supports the non-standard `-0` option for reading nul-terminated arguments.

To run the unpacking in from `xargs`, it would be easiest to do in in a `sh -c` child shell:

```
printf '%s\0' *.tar |
xargs -0 -P 4 -I {} sh -c 'dir=${1%.tar}; mkdir -- "$dir" && tar -x -f "$1" -C "$dir"' sh {}
```

Within the `sh -c` shell script, `$1` would be the same as `$archive` in our initial command, and the script would be started once for each archive. The `-P 4` option to `xargs` would run four extractions in parallel, if your implementation of `xargs` supports the `-P` option.